# Codeigniter PHP: How do I use explode in codeigniter to find between 2 integers

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, explode

I have a select box with the choice of "very low", "low", "medium", "high" and "very high" to choose between 0-19,20-39 etc up to 100.

Model:

```
if  ($this->input->post('interest_rating') != "")  
{
    $range = explode($this->input->post(' ','interest_rating'));
    $this->db->where('webinar_event.interest_rating >= ', $range[0]);
    $this->db->where('webinar_event.interest_rating <= ', $range[1]);
}
```

I get 2 separate errors
1)

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Wrong parameter count for explode()

Filename: models/hp_model.php

Line Number: 128

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064
```

2)

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'AND`webinar_event`.`interest_rating`<=' at line 5`

```
SELECT * FROM (`health_professional`) JOIN `webinar_event` ON `webinar_event`.`hpid` = `health_professional`.`hpid` WHERE `webinar_event`.`interest_rating` >= AND `webinar_event`.`interest_rating` <=
```

Filename: D:\Development\PfizerWebinar\web\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Error number 1

You have to give 2 parameters for `explode()` function 
first one must be the delemeter and second must be the string
Like  `explode(delemeter,string)`

So your explode must be  `$range = explode(' ', $this->input->post('interest_rating'));`
Error number 2

```
SELECT * FROM (`health_professional`) JOIN `webinar_event` ON `webinar_event`.`hpid` = `health_professional`.`hpid` WHERE `webinar_event`.`interest_rating` >= 'somevalue' AND `webinar_event`.`interest_rating` <= 'somevalue'
```

You dont have value associated in the query condition